# Use javascript to pre-populate onclick content

Tags: javascript, button

I have a button with an onclick like:

```
<button id="startEdit" onclick="editMe('xxxx')">Edit This Record</button>
```

Using javascript how can I pre-populate and replace the 'xxxx' content with something else?

I tried something like :

```
<script>
document.getElementById("startEdit").innerHTML = 'newstuff';
</script>
```

... but that just replaced the 'Edit This Record' part. I want it to replace the 'xxxx' area..

Thanks
Dave

Comment: i would use a model state for something like that

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I am a bit of a newbie - can you provide more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you want to do but i am guessing you want to pass an argument to the event handler

```js
<script>

document.getElementById("startEdit").onclick = (function(arg){

  return function editMe(){
// body of function that will be executed when you click on button here
//use 'xxxx' here as arg
  console.log(arg);
  }

})('xxxx');

</script>
```